# Qt save Picture within non-picture File

Tags: file, qt, save, image

How would I save a picture within any file (and not overwrite the existing data in it) and then be able to access it later? (for example, if it was the picture at the index of 0, you would access it by specifying 0 later, or hopefully something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use method:

```
bool QPixmap::save ( "fileName", const char * format = 0, int quality = -1 ) const
```